# Taking values from Radio button with different names using Javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, radio-button

I want to take values from Radio button with different names and store in an array in javascript I am not able to figure out how to do that. I am able to take value for one name, but not for multiple name radios.

Comment: What's your code so far?

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/zkhj9/1/

If this is what you mean heres a quick example.

**JS**

```
var valArr = [],
    group1 = document.getElementsByName("g1"),
    group2 = document.getElementsByName("g2");

for(var i = 0; i < group1.length; i++){
    valArr.push(group1[i].value);   
}

for(var i = 0; i < group2.length; i++){
    valArr.push(group2[i].value);   
}

var result = document.getElementById("result");

result.innerHTML = valArr.toString();
```

**Markup**

```
<h2>Group 1</h2>
<input type="radio" name="g1" value="g1_opt1">opt1</input>
<input type="radio" name="g1" value="g1_opt2">opt2</input>
<br/>
<h2>Group 2</h2>
<input type="radio" name="g2" value="g2_opt1">opt1</input>
<input type="radio" name="g2" value="g2_opt2">opt2</input>
<h2>Result</h2>
<div id="result">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But the matter is I m making an online test module, in that at a time only 1 question is displayed with options as radio button. So for that I want that whenever a user click submit for a particular Question, the value of that specific question be passed.
Or I can say, I want to pass the name of the element as a parameter to the javascript function to as document.getElementByName(parameter).